# Selecting text on question/answers tricky

Tags: bug, user-interface, android-app

When selecting text in posts in Android, you get those fine-tune selectors that you get to drag around. However, this is messed up by the fact that you also can swipe left/right to toggle between questions/answers.

To enter fine-tune select, long press on the text. From that word, use the fine-tune handles to cover as much text as you want to select (to copy-paste as a quote perhaps?).

**Expected result:** Able to use control handles to select.

**Actual result:** Screen swipes left/right, and control of the select handles are **lost**.

---

**Exhibit A:**

[image]

Comment: Cannot be reproduced anymore due to Q&A page renewal (since v1.0.69), removing the tabs and showing both Q&A on the same thread.

Answer (score -2):

selecting text in posts in Android, you those this is messed up by the fact that you also can swipe left/right to toggle between questions/answer for this process you change  modification in the web.xml file form there you will do it.

Comment: Perhaps you have a good suggestion, care to make your answer clearer?